# Dynamic forwarding: suppress Incomplete Implementation warning

Tags: objective-c, xcode, llvm, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I have a class exposing some methods, whose implementation is provided by an inner object.

I'm using forward invocation to dispatch at runtime the method calls to the inner object, but XCode is complaining since it cannot find an implementation of the declared methods.

I found some other similar questions on SO, but all of them were solved with a design change.

I don't mean to have a discussion about the design here, but if anybody has some suggestion about it I have an [open question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20749/code-review-of-forward-invocation) on Code Review, which is more suitable for such kind of discussions.

My question is here is whether a method to turn off the `Incomplete Implementation` warning in XCode exists.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can suppress `Incomplete Implementation` warnings by adding

```
  #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wincomplete-implementation"
```

just above the `@implementation`

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

After being told in the comments that this didn't work for someone and finding out the reason was because it was a different warning they were getting I have done a bit of playing around and been able to solve there issue to so I thought I would update this answer to include theirs and for `GCC` ignores as well. So for the issue for `@Tony` the following should work

```
  #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wprotocol"
```

For anyone wanting to know the `GCC` compiler version it is

```
  #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wprotocol"

  #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wincomplete-implementation"
```

I will also make a point that all these `diagnotstic ignores` can also be done by specifying the setting on a per file basis by going to `XCODE Project >> Target >> Build Phases >> Compile Sources` and adding a compiler-flag so you would just add `-Wprotocol` or `Wincomplete-implementation` or whatever compiler-flag you needed.

Hope this update helps all if anymore need I will update my answer to include.

**EDIT 2**

I was doing a bit more digging around about this an came across the [Clang Compliler User's Manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#diagnostics_pragmas) so I thought that this would be interesting and helpful to anyone having issues around this area still.

I have also found another way that you can use these `#pragma diagnostic ignores` and that is you can `push` and `pop` them so if you wanted to just ignore a particular section of the file and not all of it then you could do the following

```
    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wmultichar"

    // And pop the warning is gone.
    char b = 'fa';

    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Remember that all these `#pragma` compile ignores can be used with `GCC` as well so the above would

```
    #pragma GCC diagnostic push
    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmultichar"

    // And pop the warning is gone.
    char b = 'fa';

    #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

The `push` and `pop` seem to work with all the `diagnostic ignores` I have tried so far.

Another one is

```
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "UnresolvedMessage"
    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "UnresolvedMessage"
```

The one for suppressing unused variables is

```
    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
        NSString *myUnusedVariable;
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

and the GCC version being

```
    #pragma GCC diagnostic push
    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
        NSString *myUnusedVariable;
    #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

A few more for ignoring warnings from unavailableInDeploymentTarget

```
    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma ide diagnostic ignored "UnavailableInDeploymentTarget"
        leftEdge.barTintColor = rightEdge.barTintColor = self.toolbar.barTintColor;
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

and performSelector leaks

```
    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    [target performSelector:cancelAction withObject:origin];
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

and deprecated declarations

```
    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:buttonTitle style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(customButtonPressed:)];
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Thanks to `DanSkeel` you can find the [entire list here](http://fuckingclangwarnings.com/)

Comment: Works great, thank you. This is exactly what I asked for so I'm going to accept your answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Sometimes people just won't shut up. How many times can I see the same "create a category" recommendation? Yes, pragmas are generally disruptive, but this solves a lot of issues, especially when dealing with Objective C isa swizzling.

Comment: Having trouble getting this to work. I'm still getting warning about it. `Method 'myMethod:' in protocol not implemented.` Any ideas?

Comment: @Tony that's a different warning. Your getting that because the protocol has either a required or optional method that needs implementing that is completely different from what this is, but I will have a look and get back to you.

Comment: Sweet, works, thanks so much. I realized this as well shortly after the comment. I was experiencing a different kind of incomplete implementation warning. By the way, does clang diagnostic push / pop work with these?

Comment: @Tony Unfortunately I haven't tried, but first thing Monday morning I will try and get back to you. I don't see why not. I will update my answer to include response.

Comment: One more question, is it possible to suppress warning for only a specific protocol?

Comment: @Tony I'm not entirely sure I can have a look. Which protocol?

Comment: For example, only surpress UITableViewDelegate protocol but not surpress UITableViewDataSource protocol.

Comment: In case if you wonder, where to find [list of all warnings](http://fuckingclangwarnings.com/)

Answer (score 26):

You can declare the methods in a class category interface:

```
@interface MyClass (ForwardedMethods)

- (void)doSomething;

@end
```

(without an implementation for the category). Then Xcode will not complain about "incomplete implementation" anymore.

Comment: Just like to add that this is called an informal protocol.

Comment: Thank you, the informal protocol trick works great I will consider using it.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: A small advantage of using an informal protocol might be that it suppresses the warnings only for the methods that you are planning to forward, and not for all methods of that class.

Comment: I agree and it is a neat solution that I will probably use. I accepted  Popeye's answer since it was exactly what I asked for, but I like the informal protocol solution as well.

Comment: I don't believe this works any more in the latest Xcode.

Comment: @iWasRobbed: I have checked again with Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7 (beta 2), and it still works.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for checking! I was unable to do this without suppressing with pragma as a class category on a class that I owned :(

Comment: I used the same technique, and added a comment on top explaining why the implementation doesn't exist. Some people tried to "fix" the missing implementation..