# How can I tell Clang to ignore `property incompatible with [super class] property type` warning?

Tags: ios, xcode, clang

I have a super class like this:

```
@protocol AOCellDelegate;

@interface AOBaseCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<AOCellDelegate>delegate;
// ... other stuff ...
@end
```

Where `AOCellDelegate` is declared in a separate `AOCellDelegate.h` file (not all controllers will care to be the cell delegate, so I don't want to force them to import it).

I have a subclass of `AOBaseCell` that looks like this:

```
@protocol AOTextCellDelegate;

@interface AOTextCell : AOBaseCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<AOTextCellDelegate>delegate;
// ... other stuff...
@end
```

Where `AOTextCellDelegate` is declared in `AOTextCellDelegate.h` as conforming to `AOCellDelegate` like this:

```
@protocol AOTextCellDelegate <AOCellDelegate>
// ... methods ...
@end
```

Xcode / Clang incorrectly gives this warning:

`property type 'id<AOTextCellDelegate>' is incompatible with type 'id<AOCellDelegate>' inherited from 'AOBaseCell'`

It *is compatible* because `AOTextCellDelegate` conforms to `AOCellDelegate`, but Clang can't tell this because `AOTextCellDelegate.h` isn't imported in `AOTextCell.h`.

How can I tell Xcode / Clang to ignore this warning on this file only?

Per this [other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078941/how-to-use-pragma-clang-diagnostics), I believe that I need to use `#pragma` to ignore it. However, I don't see a warning identifier specified in the log (just the above message).

Comment: Just as a note, you can find the warning message name in the debug output pane, if you expand the warning in question (It's the rightmost icon on the left pane, you will see the details after selecting the build session in question)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a way to use `#pragma` to silence this warning. However, I was able to let Clang know that the subclass `delegate` property was compatible with the super `delegate` property by doing the following:

```
@protcol AOCellDelegate; // technically, not needed because it's imported from super header
@protocol AOTextCellDelegate;

@interface AOTextCell : AOBaseCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<AOCellDelegate, AOTextCellDelegate>delegate;
// ... other stuff...
@end
```