# Suppress Xcode Warnings

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I currently have these two warnings:

> > Warning: Ignored symbols were detected in this build. In some cases ignored symbols could cause incorrect finalization. This may be caused by different static libraries containing the same symbol.

This warning wont change my app at all, so how would I suppress this warning?

> > warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch armv7)

This warning only appears when I build for "Release", is there anyway I can fix this warning or suppress it?

Thanks

Comment: What you are looking for is would be something very similar to the answer I have given on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444203/dynamic-forwarding-suppress-incomplete-implementation-warning/14444603#14444603

Comment: Actually I just reread your question. These aren't warnings in the code itself or they but in the build configuration, am I correct? If I am my link will not actually work (Good to know though).

Comment: Yeah, these errors only appear when I build.

Comment: Oh ok then my link is definitely no use in this situation though I would still recommend reading it as it is useful.